# Google Cloud Dataflow Template Initialization fails

Tags: google-cloud-platform, virtual-machine, google-cloud-dataflow, google-cloud-compute-engine

Trying to initialize a template in Google Cloud Dataflow, region europe-west3 (must-have, cant use antoher region unfortunately due to different limitation)

When the Job is starting, 2 things should happen as far as I understand:

1. VM Instance for Launcher should initialize
2. the Launcher should initialize the Workers that will perform the job

Unfortunately, the default machine type for Launcher is n1-standard-1, and for some reason, it's an unavailable resource in europe-west3.

When I try to manually create an instance of n1-standard-1, it fails for the same reason.
When I try to manually create an instance of, for example, e2-medium, it works.

I searched everywhere and can't find a way to alter the default Launcher machine type, or to provide a parameter that will use a different machine type for launching.

So as a result, I am unable to launch my job on the region.

Google documentation recommends to switch the region, but I can't do that as I mentioned before.